# How to search for a parseable date in a String

Tags: java, regex, date

I have Strings that may or may not contain dates to be parsed (for example with classes like [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (since java 8) or [java.text.DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html))

Example:

> search for a date of the format `yyMMdd HH-mm-ss` 
>      in the String `This was happend at: 140327 12-08-12, yeah.`

The format of date may vary, so I cannot use a predefined regex.

What's the best way to search for so a date in a String?
Is it possible to get a regex from DateTimeFormatter, for example?

My only idea would be to count the `y`, `M`, `d` and so on, creating a regex for it, but it seems so ugly as my example above...

**Edit:**

the date parsing classes are precised above now.

But the exact parser isn't so important:
I need a couple of date parser pattern and regex pattern to search for a date in a String and than to parse the found String.

The exact syntax used by the parsers pattern isn't so important too, it can be used another syntax as in the example above.

**I don't know the exact date format at compile time.** The user will enter the date format pattern (like `yyMMdd HH-mm-ss`), and than I have to search for a date with this pattern in the String. (I can write an own function to transform the date format pattern into a regex pattern but... maybe thats allready exists?)

Comment: First, I'd recommend to provide links that describe what you call DateTimeFormatter, DateFormat. Second, it's not clear what's the set of possible formats. Without describing it, you will hardly solve you problem and we will hadrly help you.

Comment: When you say "may or may not contain dates to be parsed with DateTimeFormatter, DateFormat or similar", I get confused. SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter or the Date Parsers could be used to parse just Month, Year or Date too. In that case any number in the string could be read as Month, Year or Date or any other Time value. Better would be to define the set of formats you look for, capture them and parse them as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

To construct a regular expression based on the user's desired datetime time format I'd simply take their format string and replace the various chunks with known regex equivalents. In otherwords, if they entered `yy` then this implies the regular expression `[0-9]{2}` whereas `yyyy` implies `[0-9]{4}`, etc.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://repl.it/C1Rc/19

**Java Code**

```java
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println( convert("yyyyMMdd") );
        System.out.println( convert("yyyy-MM-dd") );
        System.out.println( convert("yyyyMMdd HH:mm") );
        System.out.println( convert("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") );
        System.out.println( convert("yyyy MMM dd") );


  }

  public static String convert(String original) {

         String Output = original;
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println(original);

        // Year
         Output = Output.replaceAll("yyyy", "[0-9]{4}");
         Output = Output.replaceAll("yy", "[0-9]{2}");

        // Month
         Output = Output.replaceAll("MMMM", "(?:January|Feburary|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)");
         Output = Output.replaceAll("MMM", "(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)");
         Output = Output.replaceAll("MM", "(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])");   // 00-12

        // Day
         Output = Output.replaceAll("dddd", "(?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)");
         Output = Output.replaceAll("ddd", "(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)");
         Output = Output.replaceAll("dd", "(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])");  //  00-31

        // Hour
         Output = Output.replaceAll("HH", "(?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])");  // 24 hour format
         Output = Output.replaceAll("hh", "(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])");  // 12 hour format

        // Minutes
         Output = Output.replaceAll("mm", "[0-5][0-9]");     // 0-59

        // Seconds
         Output = Output.replaceAll("ss", "[0-5][0-9]");    // 0-59


        // Meridian
         Output = Output.replaceAll("EE", "(?:AM|PM)");     // AM or PM
         Output = Output.replaceAll("ee", "(?:am|pm)");     // am or pm

     //   System.out.println(Output);
    return Output; 
  }

  }
```

**Sample Output**

```
yyyyMMdd
[0-9]{4}(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])

yyyy-MM-dd
[0-9]{4}-(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])-(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])

yyyyMMdd HH:mm
[0-9]{4}(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01]) (?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]

yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss
[0-9]{4}(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01]) (?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]

yyyy MMM dd
[0-9]{4} (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])
```

Comment: This code does exactly what I wanted for. The standad java libraries doesn't offers any similar? (Perhaps avoiding so many replacements - but the regex creation probably don't would occur so many times, don't affecting the performance.)

Comment: I'd run this only once each time the user changes their raw format and store it in the datasbase alongside their raw format. If you're happy with the answer then please mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

You only provided one format that your date would be in.

```
([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\s+([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This expression will:

- match a date and time in the format `yyMMdd hh-mm-ss`
- capture each of the date values in their own capture group

  - group 0 gets the entire date time
  - group 1 gets the year
  - group 2 gets the month
  - group 3 gets the day
  - group 4 gets the hour
  - group 5 gets the minute
  - group 6 gets the second

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oR3dJ0/1

**Sample Text**

> Example: search for a date of the format "yyMMdd HH-mm-ss" in the String "This was happend at: 140327 12-08-12, yeah."

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
0.  [95-110]    `140327 12-08-12`
1.  [95-97]     `14`
2.  [97-99]     `03`
3.  [99-101]    `27`
4.  [102-104]   `12`
5.  [105-107]   `08`
6.  [108-110]   `12`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \6:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Good explanation, but... I don't know the exact date format at compile time. If it doesn't exists any other possibility, I will write my own date format pattern to regex pattern converter.

Comment: Whether you write your own or use a regex you will still need to settle on a set of accepted formats.  `yyyyMMdd` 20160708 could be interrupted as 2016 Aug 07. Adding the various time formats and you'll see that the problem complexity increases.

Comment: Of course the number of acceptable date/time formats is limited by the parser used. And the user will get the exact format to search for. If the user enters `yyyyMMdd`, the regex generated to search for dates in this format must not find `"2016 Aug 07"`.